# Java swing combo box only calling listener once

Tags: java, swing

Very new to Java and Swing, and I have been playing with a swing gui application. It generated some code for my combo box:

```
comboBox.addActionListener(EventHandler.create(ActionListener.class, TestController, "changeSomething"));
```

and i also have this:

```
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class StudyPlanController {
    private JComboBox factors;

    public void changeSomething() {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "change!");
    }
}
```

I have 2 questions.

1. When I change the selected item in the combo box i get the message "change!" only the first time it is changed. Why is this?
2. When googling for a solution, all the code for setting up the listener was different to the code generated for me. e.g

   box.addItemListener(new ItemListener(){
       public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e){
           System.out.println(e.getItem() + " " + e.getStateChange() );
       }
   });

Is the way i'm createing the listener correct? why are there two ways to do this?

Thanks

Comment: What tool generated that code?

Comment: @jackrabbit - http://www.mindsilver.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For [JComboBox](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html) is better implements [ItemListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/itemlistener.html), but this [Listener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/index.html) is always called twice `SELECTED` and `DESELECTED`, you can check that if event is `SELECTED/DESELECTED`

```
   myComboBox.addItemListener(new ItemListener() {

        @Override
        public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
            if (e.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED) {
                //some stuff
            }
        }
    });
```

You can use [ActionListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html), but I suggest to use that for changing itself own `JComboBox's` properties or methods, not to ouside from `JComboBox`, to ouside somewhere to the GUI

You can use [EventHandler](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/beans/EventHandler.html), but better would be start to leaning basic stuff before

Answer (score 2):

First an answer about EventHandler. Normally event handling is done as @mKorbel says. For many event listeners classes there are specific methods getting invoked on an event. This can lead to many anonymous inner classes. Therefore **EventHandler** was introduced. It is more efficient using reflection, and creates less objects. See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/beans/EventHandler.html

Secondly, why it went wrong: I would expect:

```
comboBox.addItemListener(ItemListener.class, textController, "doSomething");
```

As @mKorbel said, because of the SELECTED test, it is better to not using EventHandler here.

Answer (score 0):

Further to the given answer I had problems with code generated by Netbeans - which it hides away in case we break it !!
While the Builder gets a quick GUI setup - and for what it does its excellent, I had faulty event code generated.
I am now in a habit of not adding events using the Builder but have an 'own written' method to set these up - especially in this case using the excellent advise above.